Not being able to receive intents from my Kotlin Application
I'm trying to make a music player app that can be controlled by intents from another app since youtube music is the default music player in most android phones and it does not listen to intents.
I set up a service inside the app that I'm using but don't know why I'm not being able to receive any intents that are sent to my app.
Service class:
class MusicService : Service() {

    private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer
    private lateinit var audioFiles: List<File>
    private var currentTrack = 0
    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private lateinit var updateRunnable: Runnable

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        // Initialize audio files from the "Music" directory
        val musicDir = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Music")
        audioFiles = musicDir.listFiles { file -> file.extension == "mp3" }?.toList() ?: emptyList()

        if (audioFiles.isNotEmpty()) {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener { nextTrack() }  // Auto-play the next track
            playTrack(currentTrack)
        }

        startForegroundService()
    }

    private fun startForegroundService() {
        val channelId = "music_service_channel"
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                "Music Player Service",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            )
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setContentTitle("Music Player")
            .setContentText("Playing: ${audioFiles.getOrNull(currentTrack)?.name ?: "Unknown"}")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_music_note)
            .build()

        startForeground(1, notification)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.i("Music Intent", "Received intent: ${intent.toString()}")
        when (intent?.action) {
            "PLAY" -> playPauseTrack()
            "PAUSE" -> playPauseTrack()
            "NEXT" -> nextTrack()
            "PREVIOUS" -> previousTrack()
            "SEEK" -> seekTo(intent.getIntExtra("SEEK_POSITION", 0))
            "TOGGLE_PLAY_PAUSE" -> playPauseTrack()
        }
        return START_STICKY
    }...
}

The manifest:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MusicPlayer"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MusicPlayer">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MusicService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="PLAY" />
                <action android:name="PAUSE" />
                <action android:name="NEXT" />
                <action android:name="PREVIOUS" />
                <action android:name="TOGGLE_PLAY_PAUSE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>

and finally, the calling code:
fun pauseMusic(context: Context) {
    val intent = Intent("PLAY").apply {
        component = ComponentName("com.example.musicplayer", ".MusicService")
    }
    context.startService(intent)


    Toast.makeText(context, "audio pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

With this code, I'm not being able to call the pause function with intents but inside the music player app, I'm being able to send and use the intents properly without any error. Why could this be? I've double checked my permissions, the package names and I've also added the service.
